# Use chain rule to express $f_x$ and $f_y$ in terms of $f_\xi$ and $f_\eta$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Consider partial differential equation:
$f_x + 2 f_y = 1$

Trick is to introduce new variables
$\xi = x$ and $\eta = 2x - y$

Using chain rule to express $f_x$ and $f_y$ in terms of $f_\xi$ and $f_\eta$ and rewrite equation 1 in terms of new variable. You should find that you can then antidifferentiate, after which you can return to the original variables. Your answer should contain an arbitrary function, and you should easily be able to check it satisfies equation 1.

Comment: Do you have any ideas of how to begin?

Comment: Don't know if this helps: $df=d\xi-f_yd\eta$. Also the function $f(x,y)=3x-y+c$ satisfies the partial d.e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $ \xi = x $

$$
\begin{align}
\eta &= 2x - y \\
\implies y &= 2x - \eta \\
&= 2 \xi - \eta
\end{align}
$$

Now,
$$
\begin{align}
f_{\eta} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \eta} &= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \eta} \\
&= f_x \cdot (0) + f_y \cdot (-1) \\
&= - f_y
\end{align}
$$
and for $ f_{\xi} $
$$
\begin{align}
f_{\xi} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \xi} &= \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \xi} \\
&= f_x + f_y \cdot (2) \\
&= 2 f_y + f_x
\end{align}
$$

$$ \therefore f_x = f_{\xi} + 2 f_{\eta} $$

Comment: So $f_{\xi}=1$? How do you solve it then?