# Partial Differential Equation Conversion

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, derivatives

Convert the partial differential equation 
$u_{x}-3u_{y}=2x$ 
from $u(x,y)$ to $u(\varepsilon, \eta)$ 
given $\varepsilon = x$ and $\eta = 3x + y$.

Edit:
Convert the partial differential equation for u(x,y) into equation for $u(\varepsilon, \eta)$. Solve this equation and then return original variables x and y to find an expression for the general solution

And it can be found that $u_\varepsilon = 2 \varepsilon$ (See Flash's answer and substitute into original differential equation). Just need to get $u(x, y)$ from $u(\varepsilon, \eta)$

Answer (score 1):

> Possible duplicate [Use chain rule to express $f_x$ and $f_y$ in terms of $f_\xi$ and $f_\eta$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/339258/27741)

Since $ \xi = x $
$$
\begin{align}
\eta &= 3x + y \\
\implies y &= \eta - 3x \\
&= \eta - 3 \xi
\end{align}
$$

Now,

$$
\begin{align}
u_{\eta} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} &= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \eta} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \eta} \\
&= u_x \cdot (0)  + u_y \cdot (+1) \\
&= u_y
\end{align}
$$

and for $ u_{\xi} $

$$
\begin{align}
u_{\xi} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} &= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \xi} \\
&= u_x + u_y \cdot (-3) \\
&= u_x - 3 u_y
\end{align}
$$

$$ \therefore u_x = u_{\xi} + 3 u_{\eta} $$

Comment: I took a look at your answer to the other question.
Just wondering why isn't f_x = f_e + 2f_n
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \varepsilon}\dfrac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} = f_\varepsilon + 2f_\eta$
Or not?

Comment: Though the second part of your answer (to the other question) seems to make sense 
$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} =\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \varepsilon}\dfrac{\partial \varepsilon}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} = -f_\eta$
Though this doesn't really help my question.

Comment: @bubblyicecream Ah, yeah. I didn't use the chain rule for first case. Let me edit them both. Thanks.

Comment: Okay.
For my question, I'm actually trying to find an expression for $u(x,y)$ and $u(\varepsilon, \eta)$ (Forgot to mention the question says "convert the partial differential equation for u(x,y) into equation for u(e, n). Solve this equation and then return original variables x and y to find an expression for the general solution". I've found that $u_\varepsilon = 2 \varepsilon$ but am not sure what to do to get the functions.